# Chrome does not open URL in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows, selenium-chromedriver

I have downloaded the latest python version(3.8.5) and google chrome version(84) and corresponding chromedriver version(84). But the browser does not respond when running the program.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

class Bot:
    def __int__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.get("www.google.com")


my_bot = Bot()


def main():
    my_bot()


if __name__ == 'main':
    main()
```

The above is my python code

Comment: Does it raise an error? What happens when you try this code?

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper No, the terminal doesn't show any error. The code executes perfectly. The browser isn't firing up

Comment: Could you describe the results you expected and the results you obtain? Right now there's not much we can do to help. Have you tried the exact instructions from the tutorial? `driver = webdriver.Chrome(); driver.get("http://www.python.org")`

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper yes, It works when I tried to remove class, main function and the rest, just only 

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("www.google.com")

The browser fire up but the website does not open

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

class Bot:
   def __init__(self, url):
       #  path to chrome driver in your local machine
       driver_path = "C:\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe"

       # Loading the chrome driver 
       self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)

       # Using the above-loaded WebDriver to open the URL in the chrome 
       # browser
       self.driver.get(url)

def main():
    # Creating a object of Bot class with URL as an input parameter
    # Don't forget to use https:// else your URL won't get open
    my_bot = Bot(url="https://www.google.com")

    # A sleep timer of 10 sec to let webdriver load the given URL and ` 
    # display it to you for 10 sec 
    sleep(10)
     
    # Closing the bot object which we created 
    # After 10 sec the bot object will be closed
    my_bot.close()

    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Calling the main function where the Bot object is created
    main()
```

Comment: a sleep  timer is important since it requires time to open the webdriver

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Its rather more easy in three lines!!

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("G:\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

And you are done!

Comment: Please don't tell people how "easy" a solution is. Everyone has different levels of knowledge, and what's easy to you is difficult to someone else (especially someone learning); it doesn't help to tell someone that they couldn't figure out something you consider "easy."

Comment: Also - I have no idea why you chose to use the domain name you did - it's not the one the OP was asking about, and seems like an offensive name to substitute. I modified it, accordingly.

Comment: i wasnt saying that is is easy , just saying that is will be good for a begenier to use this lines
still if anyone offended i am sorry